# ping failing from master to guest hosts in a virtualized environment created using xen

Tags: virtualization, xen

I am trying to configure virtualized hosts on  RHEL 5 using xen
virtualization technology.
I was able to successfully create two virtualized machines using virt-manager .
The issue for me is that I am not able to ping from the master machine
to the guest machines and vice versa .
But I can ping among the guest machines.

The following are the settings on the master machine:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:??:03:?8:99
          inet addr:192.168.1.2 (from DHCP server)
Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

On the guest machines the ips are configured using static IP:The ip
are as follows:

node1:192.168.1.3
node2:192.168.1.5

While configuring the guest machines using "virt-manager" , Under the
"Network Settings(to connect the new virtual machine to the host
network)" , I selected "Virtual network (Defualt) " . Apart from
default I could not see any option under Virtual Network .

Where I went wrong ? What I want is that I should be able to ping from
master machine to the guest machines and vice versa.
Any help will be highly appreciated . If you need any other info
please let me know .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I recently solved a RHEL VM issue by disabling Xen and making sure the normal config files (/etc/hosts, /etc/host.conf, /etc/resolv.conf, etc.) didn't have anything unusual in them.

The bottom line in my case ended up being xenbr0 not being properly configured as a bridge and that, in turn, blocked traffic out to the network from my virtual RHEL server.

You might try looking into your the routing you have set up to see if anything looks like it might be blocking traffic (you can use the route command or look under whichever network GUI you're using - typically under an IPv4 section of some sorts).